# Gestures in Android Talkback

Tags: android, gestures, talkback, accessibility

There are many gestures assigned in Talk-back. For instance all the L- gestures such as

- Swipe up then right
- Swipe up then left
- Swipe left then up
- Swipe left then down
- so on

I learnt that we can assign these gestures to different actions in Talk-back settings. But can we assign them to different actions programatically? Is it possible to create new gestures similar to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessibility services have a method that allows you to detect these gestures.  Override it, no need to create new gestures at all!

```
class YourService extends AccessibilityService {
    @Override
    public boolean onGesture(int gestureId) {
        switch (gestureId) {
            case GESTURE_SWIPE_LEFT_AND_RIGHT:
                doStuff();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as those that also describe how the code works.